# Checking R code with TRAVIS CI gives error: The command "grep -q -R "WARNING" "${RCHECK_DIR}/00check.log"" exited with 0

Tags: r, travis-ci

I'm building and checking my R-package code using TRAVIS CI. The package build with a pass; but I do not think the code is checked properly. I'm getting the following error:

`The command "grep -q -R "WARNING" "${RCHECK_DIR}/00check.log"" exited with 0.`

My .travis.ci file looks like this:

```
language: R
cache: packages

warnings_are_errors: true

env:
 global:
   - _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_: false


r_packages:
  - covr

after_success:
  - Rscript -e 'library(covr); codecov()'
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error. Travis-CI executes test commands and reports whether each command succeeds (exit code 0) or fails (exit code not equal to 0).  **However, your package is not being tested correctly.**

The command `grep -q -R "WARNING" "${RCHECK_DIR}/00check.log"` checks whether there were any WARNINGs in the package build log. From `man grep`:

> EXIT STATUS
>
> Normally the exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error occurred.  However, if the -q or --quiet or --silent is used and a line is selected, the exit status is 0 even if an error occurred.

So because of `-q`, your command will "succeed" regardless of whether there are any warnings in your build log. You need to remove `-q` and invert the exit code with `!`, so that the command succeeds (exit code 0) if no warnings are found, and fails (exit code not zero) otherwise:

```
! grep -R "WARNING" "${RCHECK_DIR}/00check.log"
```

Comment: Am I understand it correclt that this should be added to the .travis.yml file? 
! grep -R "WARNING" "${RCHECK_DIR}/00check.log"
Please note that I added the code currently in my travis file.

Comment: @Gorp Yes, it should go under `script:` in your `.travis.yml`, along with any additional test commands you want to run. I think you may want to include a similar command to `grep` for ERROR as well.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. `R CMD CHECK` will exit with a non-zero code if there are ERRORs. The `grep` command checks for additional warnings.

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error message when using the above line under "script:":
$ grep -R "WARNING" "${RCHECK_DIR}/00check.log"
grep: /00check.log: No such file or directory
The command "grep -R "WARNING" "${RCHECK_DIR}/00check.log"" exited with 2.

Any idea? THANKS!

Comment: @Gorp How did you run the original command in your question?

Comment: I did not run it originally. In the question I have the entire yml file; which gave the error. And after your suggestion I added: 
script: ! grep -R "WARNING" "${RCHECK_DIR}/00check.log"
(FYI I have gotten this to work with Github Actions linked to codecov so Im happy :), but this might be good for others... either way thank you every so much for your help!!)